# How to normalize the data to [0, 1] in R with data similar to χ²-distribution without shrinking lower values too much?

Tags: r, data-mining, data-transformation, normalization, scales

I want to normalize the data to [0,1], but the distribution of this array is quite not regular, having large quantity of low values and small quantity of large values, almost 80% values of data are in the range of **`[min(data), 3*min(data)/4+1*max(data)/4]`**, and the distribution of data in this range is quite like to *normal distribution*.

so the whole dataset is similar to *χ²-distribution*. The information of this data is listed as below,

```
  max(data)
  25418
  min(data)
  104
  length(data)
  971
  plot(density(data))
```

[image]

I have try use the method of dividing the whole data by *max(x) - min(x)*

```
normalized <- function(data){
    return (apply(data, FUN = function(x) (x-min(x))/(max(x)-min(x)))
}
```

and scale in R

```
data <- scale(data)
```

But the first method will has a great impact on the majority of lower data by shrinking them close to 0, which will lose a lot of data information, and the second method does scale the data between [0, 1].

The reason why I want to normalize the data, is because I want to use this data into a **probabilistic model** for analysis. Frankly speaking, I want to scale this data to the range between [0, 1], which is using as probability values in the model, and that has nothing to do with current distribution. But when I using the liner normalization, the model doesn't fit the data very well and give a very poor performance, so I guess it might be related to my method of normalization, shrinking the data too much.

So the method of normalization I'm looking for, can make sure the large values closes to 1, and in the same time can also present the major values well(don't shrink them too much).

Comment: why not tranform the data prior to standardizing it? It seems like sqrt or log transformation might help, but you can look into other types as well.

Comment: As far as I'm concerned, the data after standardization is not in the range between [0,1]. Except for sqrt or log transformation, do you know any else methods or some materials can help me in this question?

Comment: if you transform and then standardize/normalize from 0 to 1, they should be; may still be skewed but less so.